# Create all possibly repeated combinations of letters

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to create an array of possibly repeated combinations of `n` elements from the letters `A` to `F`. Each combination should be an array. For `n` = 4 for example, the result should be:

```
[[A, A, A, A], [A, A, A, B], [A, A, A, C], ..., [F, F, F, F]]
```

without significance in order among the elements (`[A, A, E, E]` and `[E, E, A, A]` would be the same).

I tried it with:

```
('A'..'F').to_a.combination(4).to_a
```

but that didn't work. I guess the task is more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `repeated_combination`:

> ('A'..'F').to_a.repeated_combination(4).to_a

Example:

```
 > ('A'..'C').to_a.repeated_combination(4).to_a
 => [["A", "A", "A", "A"], ["A", "A", "A", "B"], ["A", "A", "A", "C"], ["A", "A", "B", "B"], ["A", "A", "B", "C"], ["A", "A", "C", "C"], ["A", "B", "B", "B"], ["A", "B", "B", "C"], ["A", "B", "C", "C"], ["A", "C", "C", "C"], ["B", "B", "B", "B"], ["B", "B", "B", "C"], ["B", "B", "C", "C"], ["B", "C", "C", "C"], ["C", "C", "C", "C"]]
```